# How do you verify ViewStateUserKey is enabled on the clientside?

Tags: asp.net, antiforgerytoken

I was looking at a web application written in .NET that I was proxying through Burp Suite and couldn't tell if it was completely protected from CSRF attacks. I know that if ViewStateMac and the ViewStateUserKey are set in the source code, the application should be pretty well protected.  However if I don't have access to source code, how would I be able to identify this?

This previous StackOverflow question kinda asked the same question but doesn't quite address what I'm asking. (I didn't have enough reputation points to add this question in the comments of the answer):

[Can I see the ViewStateUserKey in html source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288299/can-i-see-the-viewstateuserkey-in-html-source)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to deduce this client-side. Inspecting the source code on the server is the only way to be sure. However, you could try pulling off a CSRF attack against your own application as a short of gut-check test that VSUK is being checked correctly on the server.

Comment: Thanks for responding Levi. As you can guess, I'm doing a penetration test on the application and wasn't sure if I could make the statement that its safe from CSRF, but I know from the referenced posting that your comments are gold.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the answered mentioned on this question: [How to demonstrate a CSRF attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812765/how-to-demonstrate-a-csrf-attack)
Particularly this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6812942/7231971

The answer suggests to create a form with a post method that will be executed by the client (person using your site) browser when a page is opened. Ex:

```
<form name="csrf_form" action="http://VULNERABLE_APP/csrf.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrf_param" value="POST_ATTACK">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">document.csrf_form.submit();</script>
```

Comment: Links are useful but if they die do does your answer, for this reason please try and post the key points from the link as well as the link. Cheers

Comment: @d219 I added the relevant information from the link I posted.